# Shifting characters in a string

Tags: javascript, html, string, character

I am trying to develop a function inside an external Javascript file that I can later call/use inside an HTML file. I need this function to take a string and shift the individual characters over one, I.E the string "ABCDE" would become "BCDEA" after going through the function. But instead of that specific string, I would like to be able to use a string variable named "key", since the string that needs to be shifted can be whatever the user enters for it. I am completely lost and unsure of what to do so any help would be appreciated.

The only thing I can think of possibly doing is subtracting the index of the first character in the string by one, so it would be -1 resulting in the code thinking that it is at the back of the string since the last character is assigned -1 but I don't know if it will even work, or how to set it up if it did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shift a string using the following function that uses simple `substring()` manipulation which is a function you can call on all strings:

```js
function shiftString(str, shift) { 
    return str.substring(shift) + str.substring(0, shift);
}
```

Running for instance `shiftString("ABCDE", 2)` will result in `"CDEAB"`, since:

- `str.substring(2) == "CDE"` (take all characters from the second index onward; strings are zero-indexed)
- `str.substring(0, 2) == "AB"` (take the 0-th index until the second index)

Comment: I entered the code you provided, but it doesn't appear to do anything. I put "shiftString(key, 1);" to call the function but nothing happened, did I do something wrong?

Comment: I cant tell what you did; if that `key` variable is a string it should work. This is a really simple function which accepts two parameters: a string and a number. There is an exact example in the answer above

Comment: Yes the key variable is a string but the value that it holds is not switching like the example I provided as well as the one you provided. I tried to do it like your example as well as my example, but it didn't work no matter what I tried. The code is not producing any errors, it's just not doing anything.

Comment: thats because this function "returns" a value. Strings are not passed by reference (in most languages they are not afaik), which means that you have to do `key = shiftString(key, 2)` to reassign it to whichever variable you want.

Comment: I got it to work now, thank you. I just have one final question. If I were to enter a negative number would it shift everything to the right instead of the left, essentially undoing everything, or would it not do anything?

Comment: Negative numbers dont work sadly. You would have to add some extra logic like `shiftString(key, key.length + shift)` if that `shift` parameter is negative. That way, when you pass `shift=-2`, you would get `key.length = 5` (for `"ABCDE"`) thus `key.length + shift = 3`, which then results in shifting the characters the other way (resulting in `"DEABC"`). You have to create some testcode yourself for this